# Django call custom middleware only when user is logged in

Tags: django, django-middleware

I have custom middleware installed in settings.py file as shown below. My question is how can this middleware be called only when a user logs in.I can get rid of my try/catch block in the `custom middleware get_username` only when user is logged in.How to go about this issue ?

settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
  ....
  ....
  'custom.api.get_username'
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
  ....   
  'custom',
```

)

custom/api.py

```
class get_username(object):
   def process_request(self, request):
     try:
        userprofile.objects.get(request.id)
        ....
        .... 
        request.session['display_name'] = display_name
        request.session.save()
    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Middleware is run every time a request or response is processed. You can't conditionally execute it. That is, if your middleware class has methods like `process_request`, `process_response` etc. they will always be called.

Try something like this:

```
class get_username(object):

   def process_request(self, request):
       if request.user.is_authenticated():
           # ...
           request.session['display_name'] = display_name
           request.session.save()
```